# How do you install Minecraft mods on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, macos

I've seen videos for Minecraft mods which add features like oil, pipes and guns.  Where can I find these mods, and how do I install them on a Mac?

Comment: There reason you're not finding "minecraft mods for mac" might be because there's no such thing. Minecraft is a cross-platform Java game, so mods aren't platform specific.

Comment: You are talking about the latest mod pack featured in the Yogscast right, the technic pack?

Comment: The answers to this question are outdated because of the new launcher for Minecraft.

Comment: In my minecraft don't work and closed the ask http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194935/how-install-mods-in-minecraft-1-8-1-on-mac

Comment: I get an updated answer there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374109/how-do-i-install-minecraft-mods-on-macos/374110#374110

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the .ZIP file
2. Extract it to some directory.
3. Go to the directory you just created.
4. Open a new Window
5. Go to `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin`
6. Look for a file called `minecraft.jar`
7. Rename that file to `minecraft.jar.zip`
8. Unzip it
9. Drag all files ending with `.CLASS` into the `minecraft.jar` FOLDER
10. Delete the `META-INF` folder.
11. You're done!

Comment: You can use [MagicLauncher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-100-mods-options-news/) to start minecraft with mods and you don't need to do any unzipping.

Comment: You're missing a step to recompress the folder.

Comment: That is not necesary, as the resulting folder is called minecraft.jar

Comment: In my Minecraft that don't work :(

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194935/how-install-mods-in-minecraft-1-8-1-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

This video is fairly old, but installing mods hasn't changed since it was made:

The [mod pack](http://www.mediafire.com/?acsbstl1lublse8)

The [instructions](http://minecrafttinkerer.tumblr.com/post/10723001271/how-to-install-technic-pack-version-2)

A tutorial for general mods:

Comment: In my Minecraft don't work http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194935/how-install-mods-in-minecraft-1-8-1-on-mac