# How can I download and install Uranium for mine craft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you install Minecraft mods on a Mac?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31363/how-do-you-install-minecraft-mods-on-a-mac)

My 11 year old son has gotten into Minecraft. He wants me to help him install some mods, including one called "Uranium."

I'm a programmer. Jar files don't scare me. But I don't know anything about Minecraft, don't know the community, and all I can find on Google is links to sketchy download sites and Youtube tutorials from other 11 year old boys.

Fortunately, I know Stack Exchange, and trust you guys a 1000 times more than the internet at large. Where can I find this Uranium mod and instructions to install it on Mac OS X?

Comment: Hi Patrick, welcome to Arqade! How to install mods on a Mac is covered already [by this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31363/how-do-you-install-minecraft-mods-on-a-mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the uranium mod by searching for it on the minecraft forums, as well as instructions to install it.

[The link to the Uranium Mod Thread.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/353866-125-uraniummod-125a-250000-downloads-open-source-yogscast/)

This mod requires the mod files itself and an additional mod to work called [Mod Loader.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v125-risugamis-mods-everything-updated/)

Mod loader, and Uranium Mod both have instructions to install (for mac) right in their respective topics.

Since there is already a question involving how to install mods on macs I'll let you combine the info from that and the info in the threads, rather than dupe it here.

Comment: should I include the instructions in the answer? I feel like if I do i'm simply copy-pasting information and generally we are not supposed to do that? Community opinions?

Comment: I would not do it as: 1. They might change 2. They are worthless if the provided link does not work.

Comment: @ayckoster how would the instructions ever be useless?

Comment: Well you need the actual setup files for the mod to work. If you have only instructions without files they are worthless.

Comment: @ender I've seen answers downvoted for _not_ including the relevant  content from the link

Comment: @ayckoster I think it's a good idea *because* the instructions might change. The forum post will probably never change, but this answer is easily updated via the wiki system.

Answer (score 2):

the most recent version of ModLoader and Minecraft are pretty simple when it comes to modding.

Before I give you comprehensive instructions, it's worth noting that for the 1.2.5 compatible version of Uranium Mod, it requires that you transfer the Uranium Mod class files directly into the minecraft.jar, does not work by placing the .rar into the "\mods" folder. If this doesn't make complete sense, read the next paragraph.

Download [Risugami's ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v125-risugamis-mods-everything-updated/), open the archive with winrar or something like it, open the minecraft.jar (found in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\bin) with the .jar with winrar, then drag and drop all of the .class files from ModLoader into minecraft.jar, and confirm. Do the same with the contents of the Uranium Mod archive.

Once you've added all these files, look in minecraft.jar for a folder called META-INF, and delete it.

Close and run minecraft.exe, and you should be good to go.

Hope this helped.